# Singular/special in the context of time

Tags: single-word-requests

I've been told that the German *einmalig* refers to the property of being special, but with an emphasis on uniqueness in time, something like "one-timely".

Do we have a word or phrase that means both **singular** and **non-recurring**, perhaps with an emphasis on being timely in relation to other events?

Comment: My employer's IT help desk will give me a 'one-time' or 'single-use' password to get into my PC; I would have to immediately choose a new regular password.

Comment: _One-off_ is often used to refer to things that are unique, for any number of reasons, including extremely good and extremely bad construction.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with *unique*, which you use in the question itself?

Comment: @JasonBassford In something like "We will be holding a unique memorial service for those who died in the fire last Wednesday," or "We will now air a unique interview that was conducted last week with the soprano just before her much-acclaimed debut took place," the inclusion of "unique" doesn't add anything to convey why that moment was chosen for either event. It's not wrong, though.

Comment: @ninemileskid I still don't understand. Something that's *unique* is singular in terms of both character and time: it hasn't happened before and it's presumed it won't or can't happen again. Describing *why* a particular time was chosen is something that isn't mentioned in your question. Had you meant it to be?

Comment: @JasonBassford Unique doesn't pick either character or time, it applies equally to both. Is there a way to focus on time over character? I tried to emphasize this in the question, but do you think there is a better way to ask it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As clarified by comments under the question, the word actually being sought is synonymous with *unique*, except that it should apply specifically to time. So, something that only occurs once—but isn't necessarily unique in itself, at least not without emphasis.

For instance:

> My birth was unique.
>   My birth was a unique event.

Without clarification, the statement could well be false. People are born all the time, so it's hardly something that's unique. Somebody hearing the simple statement could ask, "How was it unique? Were you born somewhere unusual?"

The sentence could be expanded with additional verbiage that would clarify the meaning:

> My birth was unique in my lifetime.
>   My birth was a unique event in my life.
>   As far as it affected me directly, my birth was unique.

This implies that the context is *your* birth as it applies to *your* life, rather than your birth as being different in nature from other births in general. However, it only works if extra words are added.

For this reason, *unique* isn't necessarily the right word to use in a simple sentence if timing and non-repetition are being emphasized.

---

An alternative is [**onetime**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/onetime):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **2** : occurring only once : ONE-SHOT
>   // with any luck, that was a *onetime* mistake

Or, using it with my example:

> My birth was a *onetime* event.

Even though births are not a onetime event, in the context of the specific sentence, the implication is very much that you're talking about *your own* birth. Because of the context, combining *my birth* with *onetime* carries that meaning in a way that isn't carried when combining *my birth* with *unique*. Probably because *unique* implies not just time but also quality or nature.

---

Idiomatic phrasal variations of this are also possible, such as [*once in a lifetime*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/once%20in%20a%20lifetime), [*once in a blue moon*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/once%20in%20a%20blue%20moon), and *once in a century*. However, they normally mean something rare rather than something that can never occur again. You could also use *never to be repeated*.

---

In theory, [**nonce**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonce) could also work:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : occurring, used, or made only once or for a special occasion
>   // a *nonce* word

However, it doesn't have common use, and it might not be understood by some people. (Or it could be stylistically awkward.)

Comment: Great answer! "My birth was a onetime event" is a perfect encapsulation of this idea, for the reasons you pointed out. Do you think "My birth was nonce" (or "My birth was a nonce?") conveys more of a sense of purpose compared to onetime?

Comment: @ninemileskid I think the use of *nonce* is normally specialized. It's not commonly used, and so sounds odd. However, technically speaking, if it didn't sound odd, *nonce* could signify purpose in addition to singularity better. Having said that, it would be difficult to justify its use in the case of your birth if you were not an only child. (As far as your parents were concerned, having multiple children would diminish the importance each one, at least in this specific sense.)

Comment: Once again, great example.